# How can I search all/single mu4e contexts?

Tags: helm, email, mu4e

I have set up a couple of contexts in `mu4e` for the different email accounts I use. I would like to have a single command to search through all of them. Is there a simple way to do this?

EDIT: Ok, I might have been mistaken - looks like it searches all contexts by default? If so, how can I restrict to a single context when searching?

Comment: I'm (also) struggling to understand the concept of contexts, so for my information: does a search indeed by default cover *all* contexts?  I suppose this would be similar to the case where contexts didn't exist, which doesn't help my understanding of what contexts are actually *for*... :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest workaround I found to this was to search using the `maildir:` query parameter (details here: https://www.djcbsoftware.nl/code/mu/mu4e/Queries.html#Queries). E.g. to search the archive of the "OldAccount" context use: `maildir:/OldAccount/Archive`